# How to implement Paging-enabled UIScrollView With Previews by not using XIB file?

Tags: iphone, ios

How do I implement Paging-enabled `UIScrollView` With Previews without using a XIB file?

I try to follow this links [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content) and [here](http://blog.proculo.de/archives/180-Paging-enabled-UIScrollView-With-Previews.html), but I cannot do it successfuly, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[self.yourScrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
```

**Edited**

Try this [link](https://github.com/alexrepty/Paging-Enabled-UIScrollView-With-Previews) for sample project

Comment: Yes, i did that, but how to preview content of my scrollview

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is you should set the Frame and content size. I think you might have set the content size. but should set frame also. like

```
[scrollview setContentSize:CGRectMake(320*5,480)];

[scrollview setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];

[scrollview setPagingEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.proculo.de/archives/180-Paging-enabled-UIScrollView-With-Previews.html Paging-enabled UIScrollView With Previews 
....
The solution to this problem is not to get the UIScrollView to use a smaller stepping size than its own frame's width, but to use a smaller UIScrollView. When you use a UIScrollView instance which doesn't take up the whole width of the screen, you can just set its clipsToBounds property to NO and it will draw outside its bounds, i.e. to the left and right of its frame. This is basically the whole secret behind this process. Reduce the size, set the property and it already shows up the way you want it to. The one remaining issue is that touch events outside the actual UIScrollView's frame will not be sent to the view and thus don't cause the view to scroll.
....
I think it could help you

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.